# Syncing data to iPad from iPhone

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I want to sync data between iPhone and iPad. I am using core data and save the data in Documents of Document Container. Since Documents is backed up by both iTunes and iCloud. Since iCloud is deprecated in latest version of Xcode. Do I have to do anything else to sync data between these iOS devices?

Answer (score 0):

Backups are not a sync mechanism. For one thing, backups are device specific. Data that gets backed up from someone's iPhone is not available to their iPad. There is no device-to-device data mixing through backups.

Putting the persistent store file in iCloud (via the iCloud file API) is not workable either. You can't just read/write the file in iCloud directly, you need to download the file first and later upload changes. Core Data isn't designed to work in that scenario. You might write code to do it, but the data would become corrupted almost immediately because Core Data isn't expecting you to mess with the persistent store like that.

If you want to sync data between devices, there are **many** options. Apple offers CloudKit, which is free and supported by Apple. Firebase is popular. Parse servers are still extremely common even though Parse itself is shutting down. Add to that Microsoft Azure and many, many others.